# Redirect with state not working in React Router 4.x

Tags: reactjs, redirect, state, react-router-v4

i simply dont have an idea why the following state on my redirect cant get accessed in the target component.

These are the routes:

```
{
        path: '/logout',
        component: () => <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: {referrer: "logout"}
        }}/>
},
{       path     : '/login',
        component: Login
}
```

And in the login component (the receiver of the /login path), i simply check for state object, which is always *undefined*:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

        if(this.props.location.state !== undefined) {
            alert("i come from logout");
        }
}
```

Of course my Login component is wrapped by HOC withRouter(). I am using react-router-config though. Dont know if this relates to it.

Anybody with a good idea on this?

Perhaps i could chose a workaround by inspecting the location.history and see if i am coming from a logout, if this is put in the history for a redirect, but i would rather understand why this state thingy doesnt work.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since `/login` is a different Route, you should have the check in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method and `not in componentDidUpdate` since the Route will mount and not re-render

```
componentDidMount() {

        if(this.props.location.state !== undefined) {
            alert("i come from logout");
        }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but this doesnt make any difference at all.

Comment: are you visiting the login screen directly too and not from logout